certificate error when using aws api gateway with custom domain
I will describe everything in English, but as my UI is German, please bear with me, if some translations are a little different then in the AWS console.
Inside AWS api gateway service, I created a REST api (regional) from an open api spec file (region: eu-central-1) and a stage "dev".
the only endpoint I have is /users and I have POST to create a user and GET to list all users (this is just to learn how it works)
It all works pretty well (when calling GET / POST https://my-api-id.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/users).
As that url does not look very nice, I want to add a custom domain (subdomain from my domain hosted on all-inkl) to dev stage of my REST api.
In all-inkl > Tools > DNS-Settings > my domain, I added a CNAME entry with prio 0 for the new subdomain my-sub.my-domain.com to "my-api-id.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com."
Then I went to AWS Certificate Manager and requested a new public certificate with dns validation. After being provided with a CNAME-name (some-string.my-sub.my-domain.com) and a CNAME-value (id1.id2.acm-validations.aws.), which I also added in my all-inkl account (similar to the first CNAME). Now the certificate was validated in AWS. (Status of the certificate is now "Success")
Next step for me, was to create a custom domain inside API Gateway using the certificate I just added and my custom sub-domain my-sub.my-domain.com
Then I assigned my api -> dev-stage to the custom domain
Sending a request to the endpoint already returns the correct data, but the ssl certificate for the response is invalid (it has the CN=*.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com). I would expect it to use the newly created certificate.
I already searched the web, but most of the answers tell me to configure something in Route 53. As my domain is hosted by all-inkl and my name resolution is already working, I doubt, this is the way to go. (I also tested it, without success)
Calls to the original url stil work, unless I deactivate the default endpoint. In that case the original url does not work and my subdomain behaves unchanged.
Does anybody have any advice for me?
(I can also provide terraform snippets, if that would be helpful)
